# sklearn - KNeighborsClassifier - ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, nearest-neighbor, valueerror

I don't know why this code doesn't work?

```py
    training_data_X    = np.array([ [1.2, 6.7, 2.7],  [2.3, 4.6, 2.2],  [0.3, 3.9, 0.8],  [2.1, 1.3, 4.3]  ])
    training_scores_Y  = np.array( [1.4, 9.2, 2.5, 2.2] )
    y_test  = np.array([ [1.2, 6.7, 2.7],  [7.6, 7.2, 0.2] ])

    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
    knn.fit(training_data_X, training_scores_Y)

    y_pred = knn.predict(y_test)
    print(y_pred)
```

I got this error:

```py
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have used the KNN Classifier whereas your problem is regression.
- You can KNN Regressor   https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html